# JavaFX Self Installer With Inno Setup 5 - Where put the modify .iss file?

Tags: java, ant, javafx, inno-setup

I am using Ant and Inno Setup to build a self deploying EXE for a JavaFX application.

For change the install folder I follow the answer of this topic

[JavaFX Self Installer With Inno Setup 5 - Allow user to change install directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28370655/5226524)

But after make change I have now a problem i don't know where put exactly the new .iss file

I use eclipse, this is my project tree :

```
Quizz
|.settings
|bin
|build
  |build
  |deploy
    |bundles
        /* Exe here when I not change the iss file */
  |dist
  |project
  |build.xml
|src
```

This is a part of my iss file, when i run him he don't find the icon and the exe file.

```
    [Files]
    Source: "Quizz\Quizz.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
    Source: "Quizz\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

    [Icons]
    Name: "{group}\Quizz"; Filename: "{app}\Quizz.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\Quizz.ico"; Check: returnTrue()
    Name: "{commondesktop}\Quizz"; Filename: "{app}\Quizz.exe";  IconFilename: "{app}\Quizz.ico"; Check: returnFalse()

   [Run]
    Filename: "{app}\Quizz.exe"; Parameters: "-Xappcds:generatecache"; Check: returnFalse()
    Filename: "{app}\Quizz.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,Quizz}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent; Check: returnTrue()
    Filename: "{app}\Quizz.exe"; Parameters: "-install -svcName ""Quizz"" -svcDesc ""Quizz"" -mainExe ""Quizz.exe""  "; Check: returnFalse()

    [UninstallRun]
    Filename: "{app}\Quizz.exe "; Parameters: "-uninstall -svcName Quizz -stopOnUninstall"; Check: returnFalse()
```

So the question is where I should put the iss file ?

If someone can help me he will be very very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find the answer but I found a workaround :

There are two `.exe` files, the application `.exe` that runs the jar, and the self-deploying `.exe` generated by Inno-Setup.

I used the Ant script to generate the application `.exe`, by changing `nativeBundles` to "all" like so:

```
    <fx:deploy 
      ...
      ...
      nativeBundles ="all"/>
```

Once run, the Ant script creates a `.jar`, `.jnlp`, the jre and the two `.exe`.

The application `.exe`, which is needed by Inno Setup, is actually generated then destroyed silently when you choose nativeBundles="exe".

So with `nativeBundle="all"` I was able to customize my Inno Setup script, so it installs the exe and the jre in the right folder.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: your modified `.iss` file should be placed in `SAME_DIR_AS_YOUR_ANT_BUILD_FILE\package\windows\` (create those folders if they don't exist). More info can be found in [this Oracle article, section 6.3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#A1308687).